# Windows 7 System Restore Log

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, logging

Is there a way of determining which files and registry values were added\deleted\modified during a Windows 7 system restore? Maybe a log file?

Comment: You might try this software to browse the shadow copies, no log file I know of.

http://www.shadowexplorer.com/

Comment: Might want to check out the 'Event Viewer' I searched through it but since I haven't done a restore ever on this laptop I couldn't spot anything that stuck out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Windows Event Viewer?

> Win key + R -> Write " EVENTVWR.MSC "

Comment: Event viewer doesn't detail the registry keys changed during a restore. It shows the time, eventID, user, machine - but not the actual changes committed.